# Implementing a way to change a JLabel from another class in my game Part 3?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jbutton, actionlistener

I am currently having trouble with being able to change the choiceDeclaration JLabel. My mindset behind the choiceDeclaration JLabel is to simply display text based on which JButton is clicked.

Here is my current code for the project:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class prompt {       
    public static void main(String []args) {

        /* Setting up the JPanel and its necessities for this program */    

        JFrame choicePrompt = new JFrame("Rock, Paper, Scissors Game");
            JPanel choicePanel = new JPanel();
            JButton rockButton = new JButton("ROCK");
            JButton scissorsButton = new JButton("SCISSORS");
            JButton paperButton = new JButton("PAPER");
            JLabel choiceDeclaration = new JLabel();

        choicePrompt.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        choicePrompt.setResizable(false);
        choicePrompt.setSize(300, 300);
        choicePrompt.setVisible(true);
        choiceDeclaration.setVisible(true);

        choicePrompt.add(choicePanel);
        choicePanel.add(choiceDeclaration);
        choicePanel.add(rockButton);
        choicePanel.add(scissorsButton);
        choicePanel.add(paperButton);

        choiceDeclaration.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
        choiceDeclaration.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

        /* ActionListeners for the JButtons */

        rockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
              /*I have not placed any code in here because I have not gotten that far*/
            }
        });

        scissorsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               /*I have not placed any code in here because I have not gotten that far*/
            }               
        });

        paperButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
               /*I have not placed any code in here because I have not gotten that far*/
            }   
        }); 
    }
}
```

I cannot use a setText method in my ActionListeners as shown below because it conflicts with my main class method a line below the declaration of my class. They are both using String in their parameters.

```
public static void main(String []args) {

    rockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        setText(String text) {
        }
    }
}
```

My concluding thought was to make another class that could use the setText method to change the JLabel on that frame. However, since JLabels cannot be called from one class to another like variables or methods, I am having trouble trying to implement this idea.

Comment: Make a getter method for it.  This is [tag:oop] programming 101.  By the time of writing GUIs, the programmer should not be needing to ask this type of question.

Comment: Break your problem down into logic units, construct units of work around these and the UI to support it. For example, you could create a PromptPane which provided the functionality you need and the supporting components around it

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate method for it...

```
public static void settext() {
    setText(String text)
}
```

then call it in your action listener...

```
rockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                settext();
            } 
        });
```

I hope this is what you meant! :)

Comment: It was a good idea; however, it doesn't seem to work when I copy and pasted the method into my program

Comment: It is, I put it outside of the main method and as soon as i copy and paste it, it shows a compiler error.